# Convert a file with Missing key frame

Tags: ffmpeg

This video file I can't convert since it always erros to:

> Missing key frame while reordering index according to edit list

I can't even read the details with:

```
ffmpeg -i missingKeyFrameProblem.mp4
```

It's this file:
https://www.quadcam.ch/missingKeyFrameProblem.mp4

With the "Free MP4 Video Converter" Software on Windows I can convert it and then it is usable but why can't ffmpeg do that?

EDIT:
As a comparison, here is a working file from the same camera:
https://www.quadcam.ch/workingFile.mp4

Comment: What does `ffprobe` say about the file, if anything? And `file` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> With the "Free MP4 Video Converter" Software on Windows I can convert it and then it is usable but why can't ffmpeg do that?

Please don't offend our favored FFmpeg software :-)
Your “Free MP4 Video Converter” simply uses FFmpeg under the hood...

> ```
> I can't even read the details with:
>
>       ffmpeg -i missingKeyFrameProblem.mp4
> ```

It has nothing with your input file — the real error is

> At least one output file must be specified.

You probably wanted `ffprobe` instead of `ffmpeg`:

```
ffprobe -i missingKeyFrameProblem.mp4
```

and it works fine.

---

This simple command

```
ffmpeg -i missingKeyFrameProblem.mp4 output.mp4
```

**does convert** your video. But

- input file (`missingKeyFrameProblem.mp4`) has duration about 58 s
- output file (`output.mp4`) has duration only about 39 s

---

The reason is the *missing keyframe at the start of your video:*

```
ffprobe -hide_banner -select_streams v -skip_frame nokey -\
  show_frames -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time,pict_type missingKeyFrameProblem.mp4
```

Output:

> ```
> ....
> ....
>   Duration: 00:00:58.45, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1463 kb/s
>     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1280x960, 1459 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 32.99 fps, 36 tbr, 10k tbn, 20k tbc (
>   default)
>     Metadata:
>       creation_time   : 2019-09-08T08:56:38.000000Z
>       handler_name    : VideoHandler
> [FRAME]
> pkt_pts_time=19.417500
> pict_type=I
> [/FRAME]
> [FRAME]
> pkt_pts_time=21.417400
> pict_type=I
> [/FRAME]
> ....
> ....
> ```

As you can see, the **first keyframe** (a.k.a. intra frame, I-frame) is at cca **19 sec** from the start of the video. So the conversion began with this frame (skipping first 19 sec), and it's the reason for shortened output file (58 s - 19 s = 38 s).

Comment: thx a lot for the detailed explanation. However ffmpeg -i missingKeyFrameProblem.mp4 output.mp4 just gives me the same error as in the introduction it won't convert not even the 39s that would be usable...

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepting and/or up voting my answer if it was useful for you (clicking the check mark and/or the upper triangle next to it).

Comment: ok strange, the windows ffmpeg does convert the video file however under my linux system ffmpeg does not convert it...

Comment: Maybe you have a very old version of FFmpeg in Linux. Compare versions in Windows and Linux (`ffmpeg -version`).

Comment: done that see: https://superuser.com/questions/1480323/ffmpeg-different-functions-between-windows-and-linux

Comment: any idea how to tell ffmpeg not to skip that 19 second? is that possible? i have such a problem in the middle of some videos, it is skipping some seconds after converting from vp8 to h264 too!!

Comment: @benyamin, if FFmpeg skipped frames, it means that without skipping them you would obtain only garbage, not something similar to the (damaged) original, only garbage. So it has no meaning to speculate how to go around it. Try using VLC player, it has embedded some mechanism to fix small damages.

Comment: @MarianD thank  you i will check it.

Comment: With MP4 and MOV demuxer, this may be an edit list problem, `-ignore_editlist true` fixed the missing key frame error for me. See [this question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/26391/ffmpeg-how-to-ignore-an-edit-list) and [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1546631/newer-version-of-ffmpeg-does-not-output-playable-file)