# FFmpeg different functions between Windows and Linux

Tags: ffmpeg

On a Windows machine with FFmpeg version:

`ffmpeg version N-93532-g772c73e61f Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers`

the conversion of the video [missingKeyFrameProblem.mp4](https://www.quadcam.ch/missingKeyFrameProblem.mp4) works.

However, on a Linux machine with version

`ffmpeg version 3.2.14-1~deb9u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers`

it fails:

```
ffmpeg -i missingKeyFrameProblem.mp4 output.mp4
```

On the Linux machine I get this error:

```
 [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55c2106c8c00] Missing key frame while reordering index according to edit list
 [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55c2106c8c00] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1280x960, 1459 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
 Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
```

How can I get the file converted on the Linux machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider: upgrading Linux ffmpeg to at least 3.3, and include option: `-ignore_editlist 1`

My results using your file:

**(1) WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) Ubuntu:**

```
ffmpeg version 3.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers

ffmpeg -ignore_editlist 1 -i missingKeyFrameProblem.mp4 output1.mp4
```

**(2) Raspbian Buster on Raspberry Pi 4:**

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.4-1+rpt1~deb10u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers

ffmpeg -ignore_editlist 1 -i missingKeyFrameProblem.mp4 output2.mp4
```

No errors reported on either system. The WSL machine is an i7 with 16 GB of RAM and successfully encoded at around 110 fps, the Raspberry Pi is a model 4 B with 4 GB of RAM and encoded at around 18 fps (!): files as here:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  11M Sep  8 19:57 missingKeyFrameProblem.mp4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9.0M Sep  8 20:12 output1.mp4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9.0M Sep  8 20:02 output2.mp4
```

The movie is of a cinder-block wall with a wooden fence on top, it is 39 seconds long.

Comment: that might be the solution but acording to apt-get install ffmpeg the version installed is already the newest...

Comment: What Linux distro and version?

Comment: Distros tend to be far behind latest releases.

Comment: For some distros you can add unofficial ppa repositories, if we knew which one, suggestions could be made.  For example, there is an unofficial PPA containing the latest packages for Ubuntu 18.04, Ubuntu 16.04, and Ubunu 14.04, or you can compile from source easily enough.

Comment: Pre-compiled ffmpeg builds for Linux here: https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: here what I got:  `Distributor ID: Debian, Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.10 (stretch), Release: 9.10, Codename: stretch` and uname -r gives me `4.19.0-0.bpo.5-amd64`

Comment: OK you have Debian Stretch; you can download a pre-compiled binary from John Van Sickle's site I linked to above. They carry all dependencies so there is no installation apart from copying the executable binary(-ies if you also want ffprobe and friends). You want this one, I think: https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/builds/ffmpeg-git-amd64-static.tar.xz

Comment: great! the pre-compiled binary did the job!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the codec is not able to obtain the pixel format from a damaged input video.

Try adding `-pixel_format yuv420p` option:

```
ffmpeg  -i  missingKeyFrameProblem.mp4   -pixel_format yuv420p    output.mp4
```

Comment: thx but did not help still the same error

Comment: Your Linux machine FFmpeg version 3.2 is pretty old — about end of 2017 (don't be confused with Copyright years — your copy was obviously built in 2019). Evidently, it has problems with your damaged video. If you can, install the current version (4.2).

Comment: 3.2.14 was released on 2019-05-14. It is the latest stable FFmpeg release from the 3.2 release branch, which was cut from master on 2016-10-26.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, I'm confused, by the news in official [FFmpeg page](https://ffmpeg.org/index.html#news) there is version 3.1.2 from 2016-08-09, then version 3.3 from 2017-04-13, so version 3.2.14 have to be between these two dates. Am I wrong?

Comment: "cut from master on 2016-10-26".

Comment: Supplying an output pixel format cannot overcome missing pixel format for an input stream. Input pixel formats can be manually set only for raw uncompressed or capture inputs.