# Newer version of ffmpeg does not output playable file

Tags: ffmpeg

This works with version 2.5.2 of ffmpeg :

```
ffmpeg.exe -i test.mp4 -f mp4 -c copy -ss 00:00:00.000 -to 00:00:00.500 -y test1.mp4
```

But I cant get it to work on newer versions.

They don't produce errors, infact they both produce the output file, but only the output from 2.5.2 plays. The output files are slightly different in size. Version 2.5.2 being larger.

Here are the outputs from the test runs:

VERSION 2.5.2

```
c:\Work\ff>ffmpeg.exe -i test.mp4 -f mp4 -c copy -ss 00:00:00.000 -to 00:00:00.500 -y test1.mp4
ffmpeg version 2.5.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Dec 30 2014 17:18:09 with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 15.100 / 54. 15.100
  libavcodec     56. 13.100 / 56. 13.100
  libavformat    56. 15.102 / 56. 15.102
  libavdevice    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
  libavfilter     5.  2.103 /  5.  2.103
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2020-04-23 19:38:19
    encoder         : Lavf58.42.100
  Duration: 00:00:30.56, start: 0.046440, bitrate: 890 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 544x408 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 780 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-23 19:38:19
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-23 19:38:19
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Output #0, mp4, to 'test1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.15.102
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 544x408 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 780 kb/s, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 12800 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-23 19:38:19
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-23 19:38:19
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   13 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=      51kB time=00:00:00.51 bitrate= 823.2kbits/s
video:41kB audio:9kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 3.384930%
```

VERSION 4.2.2

```
c:\Work\ff>ffmpeg.exe -i test.mp4 -f mp4 -c copy -ss 00:00:00.000 -to 00:00:00.500 -y test1.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20200122
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2020-04-23T19:38:19.000000Z
    encoder         : Lavf58.42.100
  Duration: 00:00:30.56, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 890 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 544x408 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 780 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-23T19:38:19.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-23T19:38:19.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Output #0, mp4, to 'test1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 544x408 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 780 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 12800 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-23T19:38:19.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-23T19:38:19.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=       9kB time=00:00:00.48 bitrate= 157.5kbits/s speed=28.7x
video:0kB audio:9kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 10.191668%
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First of all, welcome to superuser! Can you please provide an exact error message?

Comment: Even better is to provide the **complete** log from the command/ffmpeg version that does not work.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1546631/edit) your question with additional details instead of posting responses to queries in an answer. Please also update your question's title with something more relevant, otherwise people may be less likely to click through and your full question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the presence of an edit list. Add the `-ignore_editlist true` input option to your command for version 4.2.2:

```
ffmpeg -y -ignore_editlist true -i input.mp4 -c copy -ss 00:00:00.000 -to 00:00:00.500 output.mp4
```

Comment: It works but I cant find any documentation. What does it do?

Comment: @pcurtis An edit list may contain duration and offset times (but not all players can use them). There are several reasons to use an edit list such as preserving sync or as a low-overhead way of trimming a file. In your case the edit list likely instructed to skip a certain number of (milli)seconds, but your `-to` value ended the file before the edit list start value. I didn't check, but I'm guessing the ancient version 2.5.2 had a different default behavior regarding edit lists. Using `-ignore_editlist true` tells the MP4 demuxer to ignore the edit list.

Comment: Thanks for the info.